# With Node.js and fetch how do I determine if the HTTP version of a site is active when it always returns response.ok = true?

Tags: node.js, fetch

**Environment:** Node.js, Express, node-fetch

**Question:** I'm attempting to use node-fetch to determine if a website is active.  This works fine for https.  However when I test http it always comes back as `ok = true`, `status = 200` & `statusText = OK`.  Even when I use random characters and letters for the url such as qwerweqr12341243124.net it always comes back the same way.  Is there a better way to use fetch to determine if the http version is active?  Is a different tool required?

**Example:** The simplified example below checks to see if there is an active `http` and `https` version of a website.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

function checkIfWebsiteExists(website) {

    let httpVersion = `http://${ website }`;
    let httpsVersion = `https://${ website }`;

    fetch(httpVersion)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log('http ok', response.ok);
            console.log('http status', response.status);
            console.log('http statusText', response.statusText);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

    fetch(httpsVersion)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log('https ok', response.ok);
            console.log('https status', response.status);
            console.log('https statusText', response.statusText);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So, node-fetch by default will automatically follow redirects.  So, if the http version of the site is doing a redirect to the https version of the site, then node-fetch will automatically follow that redirect and end up getting you the content from the https version of the site (without telling you).

If you want to not automatically follow the redirect so you can see the real http status that comes back from the `http` version of the site, then add this option to your node-fetch call:

```
fetch(httpVersion, { redirect: 'manual' })
```

Then, when you run your code on a site that does automatic redirection such as `www.stackoverflow.com`, you will get a 301 status for the http version of the request.

```
http ok false
http status 301
http statusText Moved Permanently
```

Comment: Hi jfriend00, interesting that helps.  But one problem I'm having is that even a random character url like fdsaf54rsafrsadfasfd.net comes back `ok = true`, `status = 200` & `statusText = OK` when I test http.  Is there a better test?

Comment: @myNewAccount - That depends entirely upon what the site's server does for a non-existent URL.  Some sites designed entirely for the browser may return a 200 and a web page for a non-existent URL.  Provide an example URL and I can take a look at it.

Comment: I'm testing user inputted URLs.  That's why I was testing crazy examples like, dfyuifioads123fsadfsadfsadf4e.com.  But on `http` no matter what I try they always come back good.  I'm checking to see if there is a header that indicates that the site isn't real but I can't find anything.  Is there a magic bullet for this sort of thing?

Comment: @myNewAccount - When I put `dfyuifioads123fsadfsadfsadf4e.com` into your code, I get an `ENOTFOUND` error.  I'm not sure how you're getting an OK out of that.

Comment: holy smokes what property is `ENOTFOUND` on?  That would work perfect!  I was about to try a whois package to see if the site was real.  Your way would be better.

Comment: @myNewAccount - It's on the error object sent to `.catch()`.  The promise that `fetch()` returns is rejecting.

Comment: Oddly enough it threw the error the first time I tried that crazy URL just as you said.  And now the bad URL works again, haha.  So crazy!  But that puts me a step forward.  I'm going to keep playing with it. `fetch(testURL).then(function(response) { console.log('it worked'); }).catch(function(error) { console.log(error); });`

Comment: @myNewAccount - I get the error every time in my setup.

Comment: I wonder if my ISP has something to do with it.  On a random URL it always sends me to `http://finder.cox.net/` plus an enormous set of queries.  Maybe because I'm on their network it intercepts the error and forwards me to one of their pages.

Comment: Yes, that's a BAD ISP.  Shame on you ISP.  Stop doing that.  They are trying to sell advertising on a bad URL.  You could change your DNS server to a public DNS server (like Google or one of the other free, public and good ones) that won't do that.